# Using installed arabic fonts on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007, arabic

I recently installed [This arabic font package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A83C0E03-8913-47A3-ACB7-8AC357627620&displaylang=AR) (for the coolness!) and I want to try writing with it but they show up as BOXES in Word 2007.

Why?  how can I make the glyphs show up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand.  I had to go to Start / Control Panel / Regional and Language Options:

from there, *Languages* tab, and select "Install files for complex script and right-to-left languages".  It asks for the XP cd, and you give it ot it then it wants to reboot.

I'm not sure THAT was necessary, but it was part of the formula anyway,

Ok, then in that same "Regional and Language" dialog, on that same *Languages* tab, I chose *"Details..."*, *Settings* tab in the dialog that comes up, *Add...*, then choose an arabic keyboard layout.

Click OK.  You should now have an `EN` language selected in your taskbar.. if you click it you can choose `AR` now and you can type arabic!

woot!